# Which type of RAM do I need and where to find it?

Tags: laptop, memory, upgrade

I want to upgrade RAM in my laptop but I'm afraid I'll buy a wrong RAM. I currently have 4gb and I'm looking to upgrade to 8gb. The laptop has 2 slots for RAM and there's one free at the moment.

I took the RAM out and took a picture:
[image]

I never bough any additional RAM for a laptop before so I have no idea what I'm looking at. I heard that when you're upgrading RAM, you need to buy the exact same piece or else it won't work?

Please help me, I'd appreciate a link to the RAM I need to buy or a full name or something, I can't understand anything that's written on the picture above.

EDIT: I found three RAMs so far that are 4gb and 1333MHz. Would any of these 3 work with what I have right now? [Link1](http://www.mimovrste.com/artikel/2440062220/pomnilnik-ram-za-prenosnik-kingston-ddr3-so-dimm-4-gb-1333-mhz-kvr1333d3s9-4g), [Link2](http://www.mimovrste.com/artikel/2440082424/pomnilnik-ram-za-prenosnik-kingston-ddr3-so-dimm-4-gb-1333-mhz-kvr13s9s8-4), [Link3](http://www.mimovrste.com/artikel/2440086529/pomnilnik-ram-za-prenosnik-crucial-ddr3-so-dimm-4-gb-1333-mhz-ct51264bf1339)

Comment: if you're unsure, buy the same RAM again. Google for the numbers on the sticker to find the correct model name.

Comment: I would buy the same RAM again but I got this one along with the laptop. I just found [this](http://cgi.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=370935852508&fromMakeTrack=true&ssPageName=VIP:watchlink:top:en) on ebay. The only difference I found so far is that this one is 1334 while the one I have is 1333. Would this one be fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are four things that really matter when buying RAM:

- [ECC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECC_memory) or not, and [buffered (registered)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECC_memory#Registered_memory) or not? Since we're talking about a PC-class system and you don't know anything specific, chances are about 99.99% or better that you want plain consumer-class non-ECC RAM. If there was ECC RAM in that laptop, you'd almost certainly know about it.
- Speed? In your case the sticker actually answers this: it says `12800`. So you want to buy PC12800 RAM.
- Connector? With a recent vintage laptop, chances are you want laptop SO-DIMMs. The way to be certain about which type memory you need, if you can't [identify the memory module that is already installed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SODIMM#Visual_identification), is to check the manual.
- Size? 4 GB, in your case.

Using different manufacturer and model RAM sticks in a setup *normally* won't cause a problem, however it might cause suboptimal performance because the BIOS decides to downclock the RAM. That said, RAM these days is so fast that you're unlikely to notice anyway, and the performance impact from doubling the amount of RAM is likely to overshadow any such effects.

[The piece you found on eBay](http://cgi.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=370935852508&fromMakeTrack=true&ssPageName=VIP:watchlink:top:en) *appears* to be compatible, however the only way to be absolutely certain would be to either ask Samsung (or whoever else built your laptop), or to simply buy it, install it and see if it works. The 1333 and 1334 *probably* refer to the memory bus data rate, which for PC12800 RAM is [1333 and 1/3 megatransfers/second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR3_SDRAM#JEDEC_standard_modules), so this difference can likely be attributed simply to rounding.

Comment: Nice answer, +1. What is exactly is ECC? Could you give a brief info?

Comment: @Varaquilex ECC is shorthand for Error Correcting Code. It's about data storage (including RAM) or transmission that can detect and *possibly* automatically correct certain classes of errors. You may want to refer to [Wikipedia's article on the subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECC_memory), as that is rather out of the scope of this question.

Comment: Oh hamming code and stuff. I know them a bit. Thanks ^^

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, it helped me a lot. It'll definately make it easier to search for a compatible RAM at a local store :)

Answer (score 0):

You can download [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) for checking hardware information.

[image]

Under the SPD tab, you can see the information of your RAM modules. Please note that since these are DDR (dual data rate) modules, the bandwidth should be multiplied by 2 for getting the operating clock speed, i.e. these are 1600 MHz modules.

> I heard that when you're upgrading RAM, you need to buy the exact same
>   piece or else it won't work?

That is a bold statement, however there is a slight chance that different modules may cause some incompatibility. Therefore, it's better to use identical RAM modules (bandwidth, manufacturer brand, even the memory size, if you can).

Once you have learnt the manufacturer, RAM capacity and operating frequency, you can search at eBay or any hardware supplier in your town.